# XSL utilizar colores para ver hora más actual

Tags: html, xml, xsl

tengo un archivo xsl que me representa datos que obtiene de varios xmls distintos entre los datos tengo un campo hora con este formato (16:05:56) al final me muestra todos los datos en una tabla dentro de un html. Me gustaría comparar ese campo con el resto de los xmls y dibujar la celda de la hora más actual. De momento tengo este código en el xsl.

```
<xsl:variable name="hora"><xsl:value-of select="Hora"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$hora = Hora">
            <td bgcolor="#0080c0">
                <xsl:value-of select="Hora"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Hora = -9999">
            <td bgcolor="#ff4d4d">
                <xsl:value-of select="Hora"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:when>
```

Cuando el dato es -9999 se ha producido un error y me lo pinta rojo esto es correcto, pero de momento no sé como obtener el valor más actual de la hora. Tal como está el código me pinta de azul la hora ya que estoy comparando si es igual el valor del campo lo he puesto como ejemplo solo.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: El valor más actual al final no lo hice, simplemente pinta la fila por estado diferente.

Comment: ¿Cómo generas ese archivo XSL ? Es probable que en el backend puedas colocar una variable "flag" que determine el valor  más actual y en el front sólo preguntas si flag = true

Comment: Ese archivo lo generé manualmente y proceso los datos con un .jar y document builder factory que me resulta en el html formateado.

Comment: En resumen lo que tengo es un .jar ejecutandose indefinidamente que va procesando diferentes archivos y va generando xml, a la vez con xsl los formatea y los muestra en html , aparte de guardar en base de datos. Lo  del flag podría funcionar pero tendría que tocar los registros previos del xml ya que si no siempre sería true.